# My user page is wider than my browser window in the new layout

Tags: bug, design

There’s not much to be said about this:

[image: Image of User Jan’s activity userpage]
**Figure 1:** part of the page is shy and hiding behind the window’s frame.

I believe in this day and age {CSS/web design/you tell me, I don’t actually do this for a living/enter correct feature here} should be smart enough to prohibit this behaviour. The window has not been reduced to an ‘everything is squashed together’ size, the badges sub-window can comfortably be scaled and so can the text below.

Just in case: No, I did not go out of my way to create this window, my browser window (and all other window’s for that matter) is always about 60 % of the total screen width on this computer.

Comment: It would probably be better to file a bug report for this on mother meta, i.e. [\[responsive-design\]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/responsive-design).

Comment: @Martin-マーチン That suggestion comes every time when I file a [tag:bug] or [tag:feature-request] on a site meta in spite of SE actually being fine with these happening decentrally.

Comment: That's how the cookie crumbles...

Comment: @Jan Theoretically, it is fine to post general issues also on a site meta. However, if already posts on main meta with more than 100 upvotes are ignored, you can imagine what happens to posts on small site metas.

Answer (score 7):

Yep! This is because we haven't made the entire site responsive yet. It's not a bug so much as still on our to-do list.

It's part of why we've asked [Help us improve the user profile and settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319375/help-us-improve-the-user-profile-and-settings) on Meta Stack Exchange. We're going to have to revamp the user profiles to make them work in responsive design, but we also want to know what you all feel would be good to either get rid of, add or rearrange in order to make the profiles more useful.

You'll likely notice other parts of the site are similarly unresponsive - review queues, for example, and the tools pages. For moderators, the moderator pages are also not responsive yet.

We're working on these pages and will hopefully have them improved and fully responsive early next year!

Thanks for noticing!